# Is there a general method to find if ideal is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algorithms, ideals

Is there an algorithm to determine if we have been given a ring $A$ and its ideal $I$, whether or not $I$ is a maximal ideal of $A$? I found that sometimes proving that ideal is maximal might be tricky, like in [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/zx.pdf) and a general algorithm is missing for example in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/rings/sage/rings/ideal.html).

Comment: In what form would you produce the ring and the ideal as *input* to such an algorithm?

Comment: It depends on how the ideal is given... For instance, suppose we consider the ideal $I = \{ f \in \mathbb Q[x] \mid f(\zeta_3) = 0 \} \unlhd \mathbb Q[x]$, where $\zeta_3 = \sum_n n^{-3}$ is [Apéry's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant).

Comment: Oh well. I think my question was stupid as there are uncountable many rings but the tape in Turing machine has countable length. So never mind for the general case. But it would be nice to see at least some general method to prove if some ideal is maximal or not. The form if input is not important at the moment, as I would like to learn first to just find out a way to prove that ideals are maximal in general case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an example where whether or not an ideal is maximal is undecidable.

Comment: well, this the beauty of algebra. Different tricks and approaches for different problems. Algorithms kills all the beauty.

Comment: If the ring is commutative, you could always take the quotient by the ideal and see if you get a field. If you do, then the ideal is maximal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $R$ be the $\mathbb Q$ vector space generated by all ordinals of cardinality less than $c$ together with the ordinal $c$. Let multiplication be given by intersection. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by all countable ordinals. Since the continuum hypothesis is undecidable, it is undecidable whether $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Lol! Did you just come up with this or do you know who did?

Comment: I just came up with it.

Comment: Wow. This is the kind of answer that makes me wish I could favorite answers.

Comment: Actually what exactly is abelianized ordinal sum?

Comment: Take the semigroup given by ordinal sum and abelianize it.

Comment: Abelianize in the sense of taking the quotient with commutators?

Comment: @Myself yes except instead of commutators it's the congruence generated by $(a+b,b+a)$.

Comment: @Myself embarrassingly enough, multiplication didn't distribute over addition with the original addition operation. With the edit, it does.